# paypal checkout javascript error - this20.getParentTemplate is not a function

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout

I am implementing paypal express checkout button into my developing wordpress plugin.

I have an edit order page, where there is a "confirm order" button, which a popup modal message confirming the total payable amount, where the checkout button is rendered.

```
$("#mdp-order-button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    mdp_render_confirm_modal();
});

function mdp_render_confirm_modal(){
    if (!$("#mdp_upload_image")[0].files[0]){
        alert("please upload an image first");
    }else{
        if(mdp_check_overlap()){
            alert("the block is either out of the grid or overlapped with other block, please place it again");
        }else{
            var current_block = $('.current_block');
            var cost = current_block.width() * current_block.height();
            $('#mdp-show-size').html("Your block is "+current_block.width()+"px X "+current_block.height()+"px");
            $('#mdp-show-cost').html("Total: "+cost);
            $('#mdp-modal').show();
            $('#mdp-close').click(function(){
                $('mdp-modal').hide();
            })
            mdp_render_paypal_button(cost)
        }
    }
}

function mdp_render_paypal_button(charge) {

    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        client: {
            sandbox:    'censored xxxxx'
        },

        payment: function() {
            return paypal.rest.payment.create(this.props.env, this.props.client, {
                transactions: [
                    {
                        amount: {
                            total:    charge,
                            currency: 'USD'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute().then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        }
    }, '#paypal-button');
}
```

When I click on the checkout button, the paypal window popup and close straight away, and error is displayed on console

```
checkout.js:4225 ppxo_xc_ppcheckout_destroy Object {timestamp: 1494405598944, windowID: "53bb903148", pageID: "84e2908f4a", host: "www.sandbox.paypal.com", path: "/webapps/hermes/button"…}
checkout.js:2021 Uncaught Error: _this20.getParentTemplate is not a function
TypeError: _this20.getParentTemplate is not a function
    at Object.onSuccess (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:9346:40)
    at _loop2 (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1077:62)
    at SyncPromise.dispatch (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1107:29)
    at SyncPromise.then (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1125:18)
    at Function.syncPromiseTry [as try] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1170:42)
    at DelegateComponent.openContainer (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:9342:55)
    at Object.onSuccess (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:8556:35)
    at _loop2 (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1077:62)
    at SyncPromise.dispatch (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1107:29)
    at SyncPromise.then (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1125:18)
    at Object.onSuccess (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:9346:40)
    at _loop2 (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1077:62)
    at SyncPromise.dispatch (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1107:29)
    at SyncPromise.then (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1125:18)
    at Function.syncPromiseTry [as try] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1170:42)
    at DelegateComponent.openContainer (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:9342:55)
    at Object.onSuccess (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:8556:35)
    at _loop2 (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1077:62)
    at SyncPromise.dispatch (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1107:29)
    at SyncPromise.then (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js?ver=4.7.4:1125:18)
    at Object._RECEIVE_MESSAGE_TYPE.(anonymous function) [as postrobot_message_response] (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:2021:118)
    at receiveMessage (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1929:73)
    at messageListener (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:1949:13)
```

I tried to search on the web but I found no similar questions nor documentation and I really have no ideas on why this happen.

Thanks in advance for the help, full sta

Comment: How are you loading checkout.js? Are you loading a specific version? Can you try entering `paypal.version` in your console and let me know

Comment: I load it direct from the URL provided from PayPal as recommended... I will check once I am home

Comment: Most likely this "https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" as I copied the sample code and modified from it, but I will check and make sure

Comment: Makes sense. If you could also paste the entire error / stack trace, that would be really useful too

Comment: The version is 4.0.47, I will add the full stack trace in my question

Comment: I think I should add that I am testing in a local environment with WAMP

Comment: Looks like you're getting a pretty old version of the script. Could you paste the entire `<script>` tag?

Comment: @bluepnume is there any way I may PM you instead...since you are the author of the checkout.js, and likely the only one answering these questions....now the windows popup but with following issues: 1. It allows me to login with one of my sandbox account the first time but return with error "PimpAbort with return code 4001" after 'Pay Now' 2. It then even after I refresh the page and re-click the button, this error comes up https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/batch/setbuyer 400 (Bad Request) 3. There are no throbber animation for the button when it is rendering like before

Comment: Yeah if you want to raise an issue over at https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues it might be easier to discuss over there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for @bluepnume help.

It is the problem with how wordpress load the script, which by default appending a query string ?ver='current_wordpress_version' to scripts that get loaded, have disabled that and now it is getting the latest version of the checkout.js

instead of just

```
wp_enqueue_script('paypal_checkout', 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js');
```

it is now

```
wp_enqueue_script('paypal_checkout', 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js',array(),null);
```